# Could not get my query done( Taking too long to run)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get an overall pass rate for some test results.

A serial number stands for an instrument. There are 107 different tests for an instrument to pass. The tests are divided into two parts:

1. Linux tests (21)
2. others (86 in total, like voltage test, light test).

An instrument will be considered as a pass in two ways.

1. standard way: It passes 107 different tests in one single run.the code is like:

   SELECt serialnumber
   FROM table 
   GROUP BY serialnumber, entries
   HAVING  COUNT (DISTINCT testcriteria ) >= 107
2. alternative way: It passes 107 different tests in one single run or
   it passes 86 other tests in one round and pass 21 Linux test in a
   later round.

   The "overalltestrunstatus" column in the table only means that an instrument passes all test in the list, but the list itself could be incomplete. (Let's say if an instrument gets an "overalltestrunstatus" but the tests it passes are < 107, it's still a failure). Sometimes, an instrument will be rerun if it fails or passed test less than a certain number. So "entry" stands for the round that this instrument is running for.

My aim here is, is to find those instrument which passes the test but not in a standard way.

My thought is to find all those instruments which have an "overalltestrunstatus" equals pass but passed tests less than 107. And then iterate through the result and every entry of an instrument. If it passes 86 other tests, I will give it a check and if passes other 21 Linux I will give it another check. Later I will count all those instruments that have two checks.

What I want is :

```
+----------------+------------+---------------+------------+
|  serial number |   entries  | others tests  | Linux tests|
+----------------+------------+---------------+------------+
|  170119904     |     1      |       yes     |    no      |
+----------------+------------+---------------+------------+
|  170119904     |     2      |       no      |    yes     |
+----------------+------------+---------------+------------+
|  180117000     |     1      |       no      |    no      |
+----------------+------------+---------------+------------+
|  180117000     |     2      |       no      |    no      |
+----------------+------------+---------------+------------+
```

So by checking whether a particular serial number has both passed others tests and Linux tests. I will be able to know it passed or not.

My problem is, every time the query ran for like 20 hours and then gave an error like "disconnected" or "some internal error occurs". I could never really get it through. Any thoughts? I really appreciate your help.

Here is the table:

```
+----------------------+--------------+----------+----------------+------------+---------+
| overalltestrunstatus | serialnumber | passfail |  testcriteria  |  testname  | Entries |
+----------------------+--------------+----------+----------------+------------+---------+
| PASS                 |    170119904 | Pass     | Backlight test | Functional |       1 |
+----------------------+--------------+----------+----------------+------------+---------++----------------------+--------------+----------+----------------+------------+---------+
| PASS                 |    170119904 | Pass     | Linux set test | Functional |       1 |
+----------------------+--------------+----------+----------------+------------+---------++----------------------+--------------+----------+----------------+------------+---------+
| PASS                 |    170119904 | Pass     | Factor    test | Functional |       1 |
+----------------------+--------------+----------+----------------+------------+---------++----------------------+--------------+----------+----------------+------------+---------+
| PASS                 |    170119904 | Pass     | Voltage   test | Functional |       1 |
+----------------------+--------------+----------+----------------+------------+---------++----------------------+--------------+----------+----------------+------------+---------+
| PASS                 |    170119904 | Pass     | Digital   test | Functional |       1 |
+----------------------+--------------+----------+----------------+------------+---------++----------------------+--------------+----------+----------------+------------+---------+
| PASS                 |    170119904 | Pass     | Detactor  test | Functional |       1 |
+----------------------+--------------+----------+----------------+------------+---------+
```

And here is my code:

```
/* -serialnumber |-- entries--|--Pass1 --|--Pass2---|
   --------------|------------|----------|----------|
*/
DECLARE @checklist TABLE
(
  serialnumber varchar(100), 
  entries int,
  passother int default  0,
  passlinux int default  0
)

DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
  serialnumber int, 
  entries int,
  passother int default  0,
  passlinux int default  0
)

-- select serial number into the table

-- PCBA 214 ge to be counted
INSERT INTO @checklist (serialnumber, entries)
    SELECT serialnumber, entries 
    FROM dbo.boardtestresults1_full_view  t2
    WHERE partnumber = 'PCBA-10214-0001' 
        AND t2.serialnumber IN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT serialnumber
        FROM dbo.boardtestresults1_full_view  
        WHERE partnumber = 'PCBA-10214-0001' AND overalltestrunstatus = 'Pass' AND serialnumber NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT serialnumber
        FROM dbo.boardtestresults1_full_view  
        WHERE partnumber = 'PCBA-10214-0001' AND overalltestrunstatus = 'Pass'
        GROUP BY serialnumber, Entries 
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT combined) >= 107))



-- check all for PCBA 10214

DECLARE @MyCursor1 CURSOR;
DECLARE @snumber VARCHAR(100); -- serailnumber
DECLARE @entries VARCHAR(100); -- entries
DECLARE @others int;
DECLARE @linux int;
DECLARE @pass1 int;
DECLARE @pass2 int;

BEGIN
    -- get serial numbers for all PCBA 214 from checklist
    SET @MyCursor1 = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT serialnumber, Entries
    FROM @checklist
    WHERE serialnumber like 'PCBA-10214-0001%' 

    -- get the roll
    OPEN @MyCursor1 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor1 
    INTO @snumber, @entries

    -- loop through
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
      /*
         YOUR ALGORITHM GOES HERE   
      */
    -- if pass the most or if pass linux
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT combined)FROM dbo.boardtestresults1_full_view WHERE  serialnumber = @snumber AND entries = @entries) >= 86)
        UPDATE @checklist SET passother = 1 WHERE serialnumber = @snumber AND entries = @entries
    ELSE IF ((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT combined)FROM dbo.boardtestresults1_full_view WHERE  serialnumber = @snumber AND entries = @entries AND testname = 'LINUX Test' AND overalltestrunstatus = 'Pass') >= 21) 
        UPDATE @checklist SET passlinux = 1 WHERE serialnumber = @snumber AND entries = @entries
    END; 

    CLOSE @MyCursor1 ; 
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor1;
END;
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide some (simplified) sample data and desired results?

Comment: Could you also try without all the DISTINCTs?

Comment: The `CURSOR` probably isn't helping the matter. Looks like it could be written in a dataset approach.

Comment: There is no fetch next within the while loop.  Looks like an infinite loop problem.

Comment: All that loop will do is slow down an otherwise fast process. In your case indefinitely. This should be a single set based update statement with a case expression.

Comment: Yep, you're just updating the same row in the first iteration of the loop, over and over and over again because you never tell it to fetch next. Grab some sample cursor code from somewhere and adapt it, rather than writing it from memory. :-) Or, better yet, stop using a cursor for this. Think about what you need to do to ***all*** the rows, not to ***each*** row.

Comment: There is an 'FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor1 ', won't it work?

Comment: You have only one FETCH NEXT outside the WHILE loop. You also need it inside the loop. Granted, this still should be set based without a CURSOR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example, the `PassFail` column is not evaluated, while it is there it has no barrings on the query. I've added a column called `TestType` to simplify the example, wasn't very clear in your use case how Linux tests were derived from the sample set, maybe TestCriteria but this makes it less ambiguous. You should be able to get to a binary for your tests, if you need further help you'll need to define all the data and we can assist.

```
declare @example as table (
    ExampleID     int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered
,   OverAllStatus nvarchar(255) not null
,   SN            int not null
,   PassFail      nvarchar(255) not null
,   TestType      bit not null
,   TestCriteria  nvarchar(255) not null
,   Entry_        int not null
);

insert into @example (OverAllStatus, SN, PassFail, TestType, TestCriteria, Entry_)
select 'PASS', 170119904, 'Pass', 0, 'Backlight test', 1 union all
select 'PASS', 170119904, 'Pass', 0, 'Factor test', 1 union all
select 'PASS', 170119904, 'Pass', 0, 'Voltage test', 1 union all
select 'PASS', 170119904, 'Pass', 0, 'Detactor test', 1 union all

select 'PASS', 170119904, 'Pass', 0, 'Backlight test', 2 union all
select 'PASS', 170119904, 'Pass', 1, 'Linux set test', 2 union all
select 'PASS', 170119904, 'Pass', 0, 'Factor test', 2 union all
select 'PASS', 170119904, 'Pass', 0, 'Voltage test', 2 union all
select 'PASS', 170119904, 'Fail', 0, 'Digital test', 2 union all
select 'PASS', 170119904, 'Pass', 0, 'Detactor test', 2 union all

select 'PASS', 180117000, 'Pass', 0, 'Backlight test', 1 union all
select 'PASS', 180117000, 'Pass', 1, 'Linux set test', 1 union all
select 'PASS', 180117000, 'Pass', 0, 'Factor test', 1 union all
select 'PASS', 180117000, 'Pass', 0, 'Digital test', 2 union all
select 'PASS', 180117000, 'Pass', 0, 'Detactor test', 1;


  --| Control Group, only those that pass but does not have 107 records (OverAllStatus)
  ;with cte as (
     select SN
          , Entry_
          , count(*) cnt
       from @example
      where OverAllStatus = 'Pass'
   group by SN, Entry_
   --| Control count - this is your 107 or the numbers of tests the SN has passed
     having count(*) < 7
            )
   --| We are setting the count of records to the Test Type or the grouping
    , cte2 as (
    select b.SN
         , a.Entry_
         , iif(TestType = 1, 'Linux', 'Other') Test
      from cte a
      join @example b
        on a.SN = b.SN
       and a.Entry_ = b.Entry_
            )
    --| Roll up the counts
    , cte3 as ( 
    select distinct a.SN
         , a.Entry_
         , count(*) over(partition by a.SN, a.Test, a.Entry_) cnt
         , a.Test
      from cte2 a
            )

  --| Pivot the result set
    select SN
         , Entry_
         , [Other]
         , [Linux]
      from (
                select SN
                     , Entry_
                     , cnt
                     , test
                  from cte3
                  ) as x
            pivot 
                (
                 max(cnt)
                 for Test in ([Other], [Linux])
                ) as p;
```

> Result Set:

```
SN          Entry_  Other   Linux
170119904   1       4       NULL
180117000   1       3       1
170119904   2       5       1
180117000   2       1       NULL
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to SQL to this may take me a while to understand and apply. Anyway, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: np, once you evaluate it, if it helps you please select it as answer. If you have any questions on the code or how to make changes please post and if I don't respond I'm sure someone will; I'll try to follow up

Comment: I'd love to but I couldn't because of my reputation is lower than 15.